# Iterate through an array of objects with deep nested objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I've a JSON array which is generated from a `Collection > Folder/Request > Request` structure.

Sample:

```
[
  {
    "name": "My Collection",
    "folders": [
      {
        "name": "bdg",
        "requests": [
          {
            "url": "https://reqres.in",
            "path": "/api/users",
            "method": "GET",
            "auth": "None",
            "httpUser": "",
            "httpPassword": "",
            "passwordFieldType": "password",
            "bearerToken": "",
            "headers": [],
            "params": [],
            "bodyParams": [],
            "rawParams": "",
            "rawInput": false,
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "requestType": "cURL",
            "name": "My Request",
            "collection": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "requests": [
      {
        "url": "https://reqres.in",
        "path": "/api/users",
        "method": "GET",
        "auth": "None",
        "httpUser": "",
        "httpPassword": "",
        "passwordFieldType": "password",
        "bearerToken": "",
        "headers": [],
        "params": [],
        "bodyParams": [],
        "rawParams": "",
        "rawInput": false,
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "requestType": "cURL",
        "name": "My Request",
        "collection": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "fndo",
    "folders": [
      {
        "name": "bdghg",
        "requests": [
          {
            "url": "https://reqres.in",
            "path": "/api/users",
            "method": "GET",
            "auth": "None",
            "httpUser": "",
            "httpPassword": "",
            "passwordFieldType": "password",
            "bearerToken": "",
            "headers": [],
            "params": [],
            "bodyParams": [],
            "rawParams": "",
            "rawInput": false,
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "requestType": "cURL",
            "name": "My Request",
            "collection": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "requests": [
      {
        "url": "https://reqres.in",
        "path": "/api/users",
        "method": "GET",
        "auth": "None",
        "httpUser": "",
        "httpPassword": "",
        "passwordFieldType": "password",
        "bearerToken": "",
        "headers": [],
        "params": [],
        "bodyParams": [],
        "rawParams": "",
        "rawInput": false,
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "requestType": "cURL",
        "name": "My Request",
        "collection": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to iterate through all nodes, arrays and objects inside this JSON. The JSON will be consisting of objects, array of objects and arrays.

I tried `Object.keys()`, `.map()` and `.forEach()` but failed in nested conditions.

An E6S solution with recursion will be a life saver.

Thank in advance!

Comment: `I tried` - show what you tried, not just references to methods you think are the ones to use. SO expects you to actually try to solve your own problem first. Also, why would you need recursion? Or can the data be more than 2 levels deep?

Comment: I must've missed the `JSON.parse()` part. And yep, only 2 levels depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the aim is to make this JSON into an object then the best solution is to parse the JSON. For example:

```
let myJson = "[
  {
    "name": "Collection 1",
  },
  {
    "name": "Collection 2",
  },
  {
    "name": "Collection 3",
  }
]"
```

The next step is to use the JSON.parse() function

```
let myObj = JSON.parse(myJson);
```

Now you can loop easily if you want

```
for(let i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++){
  console.log(myObj[i].name);
}
```

Or just access any of the properties directly

```
let name1 = myObj[0].name;
```

Comment: i wonder is there any alternative loop method in ES6 that could make more concise implementation? Anyway, that was a quick answer and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: `myObj.foreach((element, index, self) => { consol.log(index + ": " + element.name) }`

Comment: foreach could be handy but then you lose the power of `continue` and `break`. `for of` is also an option `for(element of myObj){ consol.log(element.name) }`, but again the index is quite handy so if you need it for calculation then I think stick with just for.

Answer (score 0):

@codingspear 's answer is exactly I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/59441109/8335089

I was able to iterate through all node with this:

```
      let collections = JSON.parse(myJson);
      for (let i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
        console.log("Collection", i + 1, collections[i].name);
        let folders = collections[i].folders;
        for (let i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
          console.log("Folder", i + 1, folders[i].name);
          let requests = collections[i].requests;
          for (let i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
            console.log("Request", i + 1, requests[i].name);
          }
        }
        let requests = collections[i].requests;
        for (let i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
          console.log("Request", i + 1, requests[i].name);
        }
      }
```